# why does printing address of a variable print random values on every execution even if its a logical address in C?

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management, operating-system

From this question : [function pointer :physical or virtual address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323946/function-pointer-physical-or-virtual-address)

I understood that when I print the address of any variable , it prints the virtual address . But I had read in books that implied that for each process , the virtual address starts from 0 and the MMU will actually take care of the address translation.

So when I execute the program many times , i see some random addresses ? Why does this happen ? Why doesn't it start from 0 ? Is the address denoting some offset from the base address of the actual process ? If so , doesn't it mean that its the physical address ?

I am running my pc on POP os and my system is also new.
Here are the values when i print the address of my variable in each execution :

```
0x7ffc62f83904
0x7ffd78dee214
0x7fff2b69f6c4
0x7ffcc89680a4
0x7ffdc5cbf514
0x7ffd00540714
0x7ffd743ac3d4
0x7ffe7c5a9914
0x7ffd1ea1d214
0x7ffe21c30d64
0x7ffe885d9de4
0x7ffc5d8432e4
0x7ffe87ebff04
0x7ffc726e88d4
0x7ffef650e684
0x7fff0a62a2f4
0x7ffe89e3aed4
0x7ffd77e596f4
0x7ffcfcf76c54
0x7fff9a2cf654
0x7ffe3a8cbf84
0x7ffc4e127704
0x7ffce1a9f894
0x7ffd908828a4
0x7ffc88b0c6b4
0x7ffc2dd04804
0x7ffda3991c24
0x7fffad288da4
0x7ffd34da2994
0x7ffc3e3dcf54
0x7ffc6780b224
0x7ffee8f41554
0x7ffd369d9c54
0x7ffe5bdfca14
0x7ffc9a772454
0x7ffe03665d04
0x7ffce0eeb234
0x7ffc4fad04a4
0x7ffea8c715e4
0x7ffc6c3eb7f4
0x7ffea32a5e24
0x7ffea7729394
0x7ffdfbd2eab4
0x7fff36934134
0x7ffe9e15b1e4
0x7ffe12a07194
0x7ffc1b2fce34
0x7ffc3a82b684
0x7ffe56aad1d4
0x7ffd00d59c54
0x7fff58636474
0x7ffdc8940964
0x7ffed8146aa4
0x7ffd81794c94
0x7ffdce6ac874
0x7fff761a79c4
0x7ffe8fc95a24
0x7ffd3fb95464
0x7ffdbceeeb84
0x7ffc1582c2d4
0x7ffd47f0e8b4
0x7ffdd55b12f4
0x7ffc802a3db4
0x7ffebe9634a4
0x7ffec809acf4
0x7ffd0dfe0354
0x7ffc80eeb8d4
0x7fff1914b3b4
0x7fff3fee60d4
0x7ffccf1febf4
0x7ffdfe68c264
0x7ffd631c8184
0x7ffd814bc3c4
0x7ffc53a2d3d4
0x7fff49d96e14
0x7ffc16144e14
0x7ffecfe11904
0x7ffeaa3dc584
0x7ffcfb3a2894
0x7fff8a6a04b4
0x7ffcf0e035f4
0x7ffe060a7654
0x7ffce2a00954
0x7ffcc81980f4
0x7ffc0c706034
0x7fff172e4f34
0x7ffd62c963e4
0x7ffcf00501a4
0x7ffeec50b044
0x7ffd0bbb2be4
0x7ffff8fbebf4
0x7ffd6e127ac4
0x7fff0f2b9714
0x7ffe8b6da014
0x7ffc58f83344
0x7ffc3aa463e4
0x7fff8b28c9d4
0x7ffe1799f8a4
0x7fffe398f734
0x7fffb3056f74
```

Should it not contain duplicates ?
Now would it contain duplicates if i run the same program multiple times in parallel which would confirm that its a virtual address and not a physical address ?

Comment: are you sure it is random? can you share your prints? if you run on pc, you probably have MMU and virtual addresses.

Comment: Please refer this link:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Answer (score 4):

No, virtual address do not need to start at zero and generally do not do so. Each operating system, program loader, and/or linker has some default memory layout. Typically nothing is mapped at address zero so that zero can act as a null pointer and cause faults if it is dereferenced. Commonly the stack is put somewhat  high in memory but adjusted by a random offset to foil attacks that rely on fixed or known addresses. That is what is causing the variation you see.

Answer (score -2):

Well the address should be the same each time you compile( 0x28fefc , as an example). No it should not start from 0 since the MMU does the translation.

Try again with this code, and see if it works :

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

   int n;
   cout << &n'
}
```

To see the value stored in an address try this, which is called dereferencing :

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
      int n = 10;
      cout << *(&n);
}
```

If the problem persists, i think is the new OS..